# scala actor post a message to head of the MailBox

Tags: scala, actor

Can a Producer actor post a message to another actor for immediate processing? i.e. post a message to the head of the Consumer MailBox instead of the tail of the Consumer MailBox?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [PriorityExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/1.2/akka/dispatch/PriorityExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher.html) I believe (here's a [short tutorial](http://thoughts.inphina.com/2011/09/19/using-akka-dispatchers-in-scala/)).

Comment: thanks @rlegendi, but which version of akka defines this class? i checked in akka-2.0.4 and akka-2.0.2, both dont have this class.

Comment: how to use PriorityExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher in my actor? i get compilation error when i do `actor.dispatcher = ` OR `self.dispatcher = `

Comment: Ha, I swear it was there a year ago or something :-) Everything in the Scala wolrd is changing a bit too fast. [Here're the updated docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/dispatchers.html) how it is done in the 2.0+ release.